# WMI Query Library C#

Tags: c#, winforms, wmi

I am having hard time understanding why there's not a single WMI query library 
in here or google pointed out. Simply interface to query WMI for information. All I can find is "write a new query like this..."-style of topics all over web which makes no sense to me while there's few hundred queries I am working with.

So, here's my current effort building one:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace hardware
{
    public class Info
    {
        public static Tuple<string[], int, int> Query(string Select, string From, string Where = null, string Answer = null, string Root = "root\\CIMV2")
        {
            int Count = 0;
            string[] Values = Select.Split(',');
            if (Where != null && Answer != null)
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Root, "SELECT " + Select + " FROM " + From + " WHERE " + Where + " = '" + Answer + "'");
                string[] res = new string[Values.Length];
                foreach (ManagementObject wQuery in s.Get())
                {
                    foreach (string value in Values)
                    {
                        res[Count] = Convert.ToString(wQuery[value]);
                        Count++;
                    }
                }
                var result = new Tuple<string[], int, int> (res, Values.Length, Count);
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher s = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Root, "SELECT " + Select + " FROM " + From);
                string[] res = new string[Values.Length];
                foreach (ManagementObject wQuery in s.Get())
                {
                    foreach (string value in Values)
                    {
                        res[Count] = Convert.ToString(wQuery[value]);
                        Count++;
                    }
                }
                var result = new Tuple<string[], int, int>(res, Values.Length, Count);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to get above in working order now for a weeks. Coming from basic string multi-dimensional array (return string[,] or string[][]) just started testing, if returning tuple (which I used few years ago successfully) would be better choice.

So, anyone know, if there is library already written?
if not, then best way to do above query from reference DLL library?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22WMI%22

Comment: Well, have to say 'WmiLight'-Project is at least interesting reading, but can't see anything else in above list of nuget, which would be even close to what I am after. Here is perfect example of what I said above, that there doesn't seem to be any library written anywhere that will simply return data with 1 line of code.

Comment: or of course it could be that I am simply too stupid to understand the point of writing whole query to application. While we should have library that does the same, threads and processes data between returns usable simply by defining container storing used method from library and store it in while processing needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old. But you can use [ORMi](https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi) library. I think it will just fit on your needs.

For example:

1) Define your class:

```
[WMIClass("Win32_Processor")]
public class Processor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [WMIProperty("NumberOfCores")]
    public int Cores { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

2) Query:

```
WMIHelper helper = new WMIHelper("root\\CimV2");

List<Processor> processors = helper.Query<Processor>().ToList();
```

3) Or lazy coding option:

```
var processors = helper.Query("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");
```

You can find more information in here:

https://github.com/nicoriff/ORMi

https://medium.com/@luque.nicolas/compare-ormi-and-traditional-net-wmi-implementation-f00db26d10a3